# How many Hecke operators span the Hecke algebra?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

This is a generalisation of my [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42809/how-many-hecke-operators-span-the-level-1-hecke-algebra) about generators for the level 1 Hecke algebra.

Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and $k \ge 1$ an integer. There's an explicit bound $S$ (the "Sturm bound") known such that if $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$ (the space of modular forms of weight $k$ and level $\Gamma$) satisfies $a_n(f) = 0$ for $0 \le n \le S$, then $f = 0$, where $a_n(f)$ denote the coefficients of the $q$-expansion of $f$ (at the cusp $\infty$).

Since $M_k(\Gamma)$ is finite-dimensional and doesn't contain any nonzero constant functions, there must actually exist some $S'$ such that if $a_n(f) = 0$ for $1 \le n \le S'$ (but with no assumption on $a_0(f)$), then in fact $f = 0$. Can one give an effective upper bound on $S'$ (in terms of $k$ and the index $[\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) : \Gamma]$)?

I'd be interested to know the answer to this even for the special case $\Gamma = \Gamma_0(N)$ or $\Gamma_1(N)$. For these groups it is equivalent to asking that the Hecke algebra acting on $M_k(\Gamma)$ is spanned by the operators $T_1, \dots, T_{S'}$ (hence the title of the question).

Comment: @David: if you don't want anyone to answer the question you should delete it.

Comment: I've decided to undelete this old question -- I did delete it because I wanted to set it as a student project, but the student didn't solve it.

Comment: Hmmm... isn't it called a "Sturm bound"?

Comment: Julian, if you read the question you'll see that I've carefully explained why what I'm looking for is not the same as the Sturm bound.

Comment: A data point: for $\Gamma_0(p)$ in weight 4, $p$ prime, the Sturm bound $S$ is $(p + 1)/3$, but the Eisenstein series $E_4(pz)$ has $a_n = 0$ for $1 \le n < p$, so $S'$ must be at least $p$.

Comment: David, do you know a good reference for sturm bounds?

Comment: Joel: see e.g. http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/newforms.html#sturm-s-theorem.